# Could not find Control in ControlParameter - prepending with ContentPlaceHolderID not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having the classic "**EditItemTemplate**"/"**Cannot find Control**" error, because I have search parameters that refer to a **ControlID** inside an **EditItemTemplate** inside a **GridView**. I've tried prepending my ControlID with the ID of the GridView (**gridview$controlID**), but it isn't working. I'm happy to resort to using "code-behind" methods if I have to, but I'd much rather understand *why* the prepending method isn't working. Any tips based on the code below?

Thanks!

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMatchEntry" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlGameWeek" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMatchSelect" DataKeyNames="MatchID,HomeTeamID,AwayTeamID" 
            DataSourceID="sdsMatches" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Matches Found" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMatchSelect">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home Team" SortExpression="HomeTeamName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
                    <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %></ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlHomeTeam" DataSourceID="sdsHomeTeams" 
                            DataTextField="HomeTeamName" DataValueField="HomeTeamID" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("HomeTeamID") %>' AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Away Team" SortExpression="AwayTeamName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
                    <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %></ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlAwayTeam" DataSourceID="sdsAwayTeams" 
                            DataTextField="AwayTeamName" DataValueField="AwayTeamID" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AwayTeamID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMatches" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>' runat="server" 
            SelectCommand="pGameWeekMatchAdminDisplay" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="GameWeekID" ControlID="ddlGameWeek" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="DivisionID" ControlID="ddlDivision" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsHomeTeams" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>' runat="server"
            SelectCommand="SELECT 'Select Home Team' AS HomeTeamName, -1 AS HomeTeamID UNION SELECT Name AS HomeTeamName, TeamID AS HomeTeamID FROM Team WHERE DivisionID = @DivisionID AND TeamID <> @AwayTeamID" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="DivisionID" ControlID="ddlDivision" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="AwayTeamID" ControlID="gvMatchSelect$ddlAwayTeam" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAwayTeams" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>' runat="server"
            SelectCommand="SELECT 'Select Away Team' AS AwayTeamName, -1 AS AwayTeamID UNION SELECT Name AS AwayTeamName, TeamID AS AwayTeamID FROM Team WHERE DivisionID = @DivisionID AND TeamID <> @HomeTeamID" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="DivisionID" ControlID="ddlDivision" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="HomeTeamID" ControlID="gvMatchSelect$ddlHomeTeam" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: How is the SqlDataSource supposed to know which `ddlHomeTeam` it is supposed to get its parameter from?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of your question. That's essentially what I'm asking.

Comment: There can be multiple instances of `ddlHomeTeam` because it exists in a `GridView`  The SqlDataSource will not know which one you're referencing.  You will likely need to rethink your design, or maybe include the SDS in your `GridView`.

Comment: @LeeCambl Did you ever find a fix? I'm running into this same problem... Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The controls are nested inside of a `GridViewRow` which implements the `INamingContainer` interface. If you're using a recent version of ASP.NET and only need single-row editing, you should be able to work around this by making the control ID static:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Comment: I'm probably going to sound quite pedantic now, but I didn't actually ask for an alternate solution, I asked why the "GridViewID$ControlID" method, which has worked for other people, doesn't work in the above. Any thoughts?

That aside, using `ClientIDMode="Static"` didn't work either.